# What does "throw in the fact" and "the escrow" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

I came across the following dialogue in an American TV show, but I do not understand the parts in bold.

(*A* is a 40-year-old divorced woman who is trying to hide her real age and pretends to be 26; she couldn’t afford her house in New Jersey and the bank has foreclosed on it. *B* is a friend of *A*. *Josh* likes *A* and thinks she is 26)

> [*A* and *B* are in a car. *A* is driving. *A* receives a text on her phone]
>
> A: Will you check that for me?
>   B: Ooh, hotty hotpants alert. It’s from Josh.
>
> [The text from Josh says: “don't make me wait till tomorrow, come over tonight”]
>
> A: Oh, nice. What should I text back?
>   B: How about, “**The escrow** on my suburban New Jersey home **is closed**, and I’m on my way to tag everything for the movers”?
>   A: Why not **throw in the fact that** I’m 40 and a baby’s head came out of
>   my Frida? [laughs]

I’m guessing *throw in the fact that* means ‘telling the fact directly’, but I’m not sure it’s really *throw in* + *the fact*. Am I misunderstanding this?

When I looked up *escrow* in the dictionary, I got the following definition:

> *Money, property, a deed, or a bond put into the custody of a third party for delivery to a grantee only after the fulfillment of the conditions specified*.

I’m guessing it must have another meaning here than what I found, because how can money be *closed*? What does it mean that the escrow is closed?

Comment: `Throw in` + `the fact that...`. Voting to close as gen-ref

Comment: The escrow closed = the sale has been finalized.  Presumably the money or deed was received by the third party, so the deal now cannot be canceled.

Comment: It makes me feel sad when seeing my question is on hold / closed for a serious English learner. I did try to look up from dictionary every time and I doubted to post a question here after being rejected by [on hold / closed] in couple of time. and tend to trust on my lousy Chinese subtitles that always translated incorrectly.

Comment: There is a place for English language learners: http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GEdgar I just moved back from there where I stayed 2 days. I like here. My question will be answered very quickly which will help to save time for my English study. You know, I need an encouragement before posting question here. Language learners are always shameful to ask questions. Feel sad..

Comment: @puputeh24 It’s not a question of where you like it, but of where the question fits. The basic criterion to distinguish where it fits best is _would a native English speaker with no special grammatical/linguistic training know and be able to explain the answer to this question?_ If the answer is yes, then it’s a question for [ell.se]; if not, it’s probably a better fit here. This case is sort of right on the border: any English speaker will understand what is meant, but not everyone will be able to explain exactly why.

Comment: If you already look things up in the dictionary before posting, it might be a good idea to include the research you've done in the body of the question. :) For example, "I heard this phrase X on TV show Y. When I looked it up in the dictionary it said it meant Z, but [specific part of Z you don't understand, or reason you are having trouble making Z make sense in context]". I'm sure you have indeed done the research, but it can help you get much better answers to your questions if you explain what it was that you didn't understand...

Comment: ... - otherwise, people may just give you the definition you already found in the dictionary! - and will help stop you getting your questions closed as off-topic too.

Comment: Also, your two questions (about "throw in the fact that" and about "the escrow closed") have nothing to do with each other, so it's probably best to post them as two separate questions to stop them being closed as too broad :) Hope that helps!

Comment: @starsplusplus Yeah, I did read the rules (including some research) here before posting and coming back from ELL. It makes me cry that like a case where a teacher tells his student. You can't ask your question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet , thanks for your comment ! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not saying you didn't, I'm just suggesting a way that you can ask your question with a smaller chance of getting it closed as off-topic. The StackExchange model can be hard to understand when you are new to it.

Comment: @starsplusplus  I understand. I really did it to avoid a question to be marked as on hold or closed topic. But I do feel stack exchange is better  than ELL where my questions were answered more expertly. That's why I'm back. haha

Comment: Think of it this way. If you were in a maths class and someone started asking lots of geography questions, it would take up a lot of the teacher's time, and waste the time of the other students, who are there to learn maths. Maybe the maths students would even stop attending if it kept happening, because they can't learn any maths, because all the teacher's time is being spent answering the questions about geography. What the teacher should do instead is to say, "I'm sorry, please come to my geography class and I'll answer your geography questions then. Right now, I have to teach maths." (...)

Comment: (...) In this way, the student gets to learn about geography in the right time and place, without disrupting the other students. That student is happy because his questions are answered, the other students are happy because they get to learn what they were there to learn, and the teacher is happy because he gets to teach both sets of students. Maybe the student even makes the other geography students happier because they get to hear the answer to the interesting geography question that they wouldn't have heard if it had been asked in the maths class! (...)

Comment: (...) In the same way, we try to separate out the StackExchange network into different sites of specialised expertise, to get learners the best answers to their questions, and to keep the teachers happy and continuing to answer questions. (After all, if the teachers leave, no one can learn!)

Comment: @puputeh24 ELL is also a part of StackExchange. I have edited your question to give you an example of how to word your question in a way that makes it less likely to be put on hold. This includes not only saying that you’ve looked something up, but also _why_ what you found doesn’t answer the question for you. If I’ve misunderstood what it is you’re unsure about, please go ahead and rephrase the points I’ve misunderstood. (In general, it’s also a good idea to give the example you don’t understand before asking the actual question.)

Comment: @starsplusplus thumbs up !

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I love your edition. I really stuck it out while typing my questions here.

Answer (score 2):

"To throw in" means to "add something to the mix" usually rather carelessly, without giving it much thought or planning.

**The cookie batter looks tasty, but could you throw in some raisins?**

**I was telling him all about our cross-country trip, and threw in how you got a speeding ticket in Kansas.**

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the term **escrow** has several uses. At its most basic level it refers to funds or other goods held by a trusted third party to insure compliance by the two main parties to a transaction. [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/escrow.asp) explains.

But in real estate the usage varies by state in the US, all based somewhat on the simple definition above. When you see a TV show or movie that says something like "my escrow closed" you can assume it was written / filmed in California, where the term has a specific meaning not common in the eastern part of the US. [This article](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/term-escrow-mean-real-estate-46555.html) covers that usage. If that link rots, google "escrow closing in California".